# RAM usage keeps creeping up

Tags: ram, memory-usage, memory-leak

Starting from a moment ago, RAM usage began to act up in a weird way. Judging from `System Monitor`, I can tell the Memory metric keeps increasing non-stop, all the way up to the full capacity and my `swap` storage. The point is from the `Process` tab in the  `System Monitor`, I don't see anything eating memory abnormally. And It's such a pain that I have to restart the machine to free it all up. What's exactly going on?

`free -m` result here:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7900        1288         126        6044        6485         236
Swap:         15624          62       15562
```

Comment: What do you see when you run `free -m` in the command line?  (Please copy/paste the text from the terminal into your question as an edit, and as text, not a screenshot, please)

Comment: looking at your `top` could help too (`man top`), identifying the processes using memory.

Comment: If you are using Chrome press `Shift` + `Esc` to monitor memory usage by tab. Some misbehaved websites with comments can chew up 1 GB every couple of hours and need to be refreshed to reclaim space.

Comment: @SYN that's just a replica of what the `System Monitor` shows I think, isn't it?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the problem persists even without Chrome open in my case.

Comment: @ThomasWard just rebooted it ten minutes ago, and it already used up 85 % memory of 8G, and still increasing. I will definitely post the result till it reaches the swap area.

Comment: @ThomasWard and I find it very strange that `used`(1288)  and `free`(126) don't add up to `total`(7900).

Comment: @JamesWong You're looking at the wrong part, honestly; the part on the right (shared, buff/cache, available) includes the allocations done by the kernel for shared memory, the buffer and cache data, etc.  That's what you get there - used + buff/cache = total, or close to it usually.  In this case you've got a *lot* of memory being used, and I'd be looking at `sudo htop` and others to see what's eating your memory.  It's entirely possible that you have something running that's eating the memory and you don't know it; `mysql` and such do this sometimes.

Comment: @ThomasWard yea, definitely. Monitoring `htop` for a while, I find that memory usage per application doesn't change at all while the whole number keeps increasing. So there doesn't seem to be anything I can do about. Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure what triggered the leak, but it may be related to Mesa and DRM stuff, because that's what got upgraded on a `sudo apt upgrade` along with update-notifier and stuff, and a reboot solved the issue for me.
On yakkety btw.

Comment: Exactly. Just updated Mesa, problem gone. Thanks a lot for your insight.